# L2L ACL issue with Cisco ASA to AWS Cloud

Tags: l2vpn, aws

Need help seeing what I am not seeing at the moment.  I have built a l2l to the AWS cloud I run a packet trace outbound and that passes but when I run packet tracer outbound in I keep getting denied by Implicit rule. I have gone over my configs and I don't see what is deny perhaps a fresh pair of eyes will see what I am not seeing.

Here is my config

```
object network dw01
host 10.20.10.103

object network dw01-NATLDN
host 10.180.0.103


object-group network Amazon.LocalLDN
network-object 10.180.0.0 255.255.255.0

object-group network Amazon-RemoteLDN
network-object 10.30.0.0 255.255.0.0


access-list OUTSIDE_cryptomap_10 extended permit ip object-group Amazon.LocalLDN object-group Amazon-RemoteLDN
access-list OUTSIDE_cryptomap_10 extended permit ip object-group Amazon-RemoteLDN object-group Amazon.LocalLDN

access-list amznLDN-filter extended permit ip host 52.56.71.96 host 208.126.125.10
access-list amznLDN-filter extended permit ip 10.30.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.180.0.0 255.255.255.0


nat (INSIDE,OUTSIDE) source static dw01 dw01-NATLDN destination static Amazon-RemoteLDN Amazon-RemoteLDN


crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn esp-aes esp-sha-hmac

crypto map OUTSIDE_map 15 match address OUTSIDE_cryptomap_10
crypto map OUTSIDE_map 15 set pfs group2
crypto map OUTSIDE_map 15 set peer 52.56.71.96 
crypto map OUTSIDE_map 15 set ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn
crypto map OUTSIDE_map 15 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto map OUTSIDE_map 15 set nat-t-disable

tunnel-group 52.56.71.96 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 52.56.71.96 general-attributes
default-group-policy Amazon-LDN
tunnel-group 52.56.71.96 ipsec-attributes
ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 10

group-policy Amazon-LDN internal
group-policy Amazon-LDN attributes
vpn-idle-timeout none
vpn-session-timeout none
vpn-filter value amznLDN-filter
vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1
```

Trace:

```
Phase: 1
Type: CAPTURE
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
Forward Flow based lookup yields rule:
in id=0x738e6b38, priority=13, domain=capture, deny=false
hits=2884362251, user_data=0x73831aa0, cs_id=0x0, l3_type=0x0
src mac=0000.0000.0000, mask=0000.0000.0000
dst mac=0000.0000.0000, mask=0000.0000.0000
input_ifc=OUTSIDE, output_ifc=any

Phase: 2
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Implicit Rule
Additional Information:
Forward Flow based lookup yields rule:
in id=0x72f221c0, priority=1, domain=permit, deny=false
hits=31054542779, user_data=0x0, cs_id=0x0, l3_type=0x8
src mac=0000.0000.0000, mask=0000.0000.0000
dst mac=0000.0000.0000, mask=0100.0000.0000
input_ifc=OUTSIDE, output_ifc=any

Phase: 3
Type: ROUTE-LOOKUP
Subtype: input
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
in 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 INSIDE

Phase: 4
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype:
Result: DROP
Config:
Implicit Rule
Additional Information:
Forward Flow based lookup yields rule:
in id=0x73cd1e50, priority=11, domain=permit, deny=true
hits=28748828, user_data=0x5, cs_id=0x0, flags=0x0, protocol=0
src ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0
dst ip/id=0.0.0.0, mask=0.0.0.0, port=0, dscp=0x0
input_ifc=OUTSIDE, output_ifc=any
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use packet-tracer for outside-to-inside traffic when it comes to tunnels terminated directly on the ASA. Have you actually tested the tunnel both directions with real traffic?

Also, you can't define your tunnels to AWS the way you have, because AWS tunnels are route-based.

AWS requires that "any" be used in the cryptomap match ACL, and that all restrictions be done via VPN-Filter or routing.  That being said, please issue the following to correct your cryptomap ACL:

```
access-list OUTSIDE_cryptomap_10 extended permit ip any object-group Amazon-RemoteLDN
no access-list OUTSIDE_cryptomap_10 extended permit ip object-group Amazon.LocalLDN object-group Amazon-RemoteLDN
no access-list OUTSIDE_cryptomap_10 extended permit ip object-group Amazon-RemoteLDN object-group Amazon.LocalLDN
```

VPN-Filters filter traffic coming in from the remote end, and are applied after the tunnel is formed (meaning it has no impact on restricting the public peering IPs, like you tried to do).  The being said, please issue the following to correct your VPN-Filter:

```
no access-list amznLDN-filter extended permit ip host 52.56.71.96 host 208.126.125.10
```

To add the redundancy/fault-tolerant tunnel config, please find the configuration script that AWS created for you to copy/paste, and locate the crypto map section and tunnel-group section for the second tunnel.  Then, on your ASA, you will need to do:

```
crypto map OUTSIDE_map 15 set peer 52.56.71.96 <secondary tunnel peer IP address goes here after the existing peer IP address>
!
tunnel-group <secondary peer IP address here> type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group <secondary peer IP address here> general-attributes
default-group-policy Amazon-LDN
tunnel-group <secondary peer IP address here> ipsec-attributes
ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 10
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93653/discussion-on-answer-by-jesse-p-l2l-acl-issue-with-cisco-asa-to-aws-cloud).

Comment: @RonMaupin There was no "extended discussion". There were questions that were all pertinent to the original topic - not just banter.

Comment: Right, but the system starts complaining when there are too many comments. I moved them to chat so that they can continue. That is what it tells you to do when there are too many comments, but nobody did that, so the system complained to me.

Comment: @RonMaupin Oh. I know it asks but I didn't know it went further than that and started alerting mods.  Good to know.

Comment: It waits until about 20 to alert the moderators. I think it is about eight that it complains to you, but then it flags a moderator at 20.